# How to tell which local branch is out of date with remote branch

Tags: git, github

I'm usually tracking many remote branches. After I do a

```
git fetch
```

to get all the latest updates from all tracking branches. Is there a single command to see which remote branch I just fetched is ahead of my local branch?

Currently, I'm manually switching to each local branch to get the message

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/xyz' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

Would be nice if there is a single command that will tell me which local branch is behind of the tracking remote branch.

EDIT: I suppose this could do this:

```
git remote show origin
```

But it requires a network connection, which should not really be needed since I already did a `git fetch`. The information should be available locally, even if possibly stale.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question

```
git branch -v
```

would do. Use double v to see the remote branch name too

```
git branch -vv
```

Example output from `git branch -vv` on an out-of-date local branch:

```
* master 3795de5 [origin/master: behind 1] Remove bad library search paths.
```

Note the "behind 1". There is another commit on the remote branch (can't tell what it is from this output) which comes after the local 3795de5 commit of "Remove bad library search paths."